# how to open profile manager in firefox in Ubuntu 21.10+ or firefox installed with snap?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, snap

How to open profile manager every time on clicking *New Window* or clicking on firefox shortcut in Ubuntu 21.10+ or Firefox installed with snap?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following are steps:

*sudo find / -type f -name firefox*.deskop* 
find following file: **/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop**

*sudo nano /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/firefox_firefox.desktop*
**[Desktop Entry]**
Exec=... **/snap/bin/firefox --profilemanager**

**[Desktop Action NewWindow]**
Exec=... **/snap/bin/firefox --profilemanager**

Answer (score 0):

Despite searching for "mint" answers, this thread came up. So whether someone is on mint or ubuntu, I might have additional info. Bhavesh gave a great answer to find the file to change.

December 2023, latest LTS version of Mint, I found 3 .desktop files (outside of Timeshift).

This is the I had to change: /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop

And in it, the Exec line was `Exec=firefox %u` and I changed it to `Exec=firefox --profilemanager`

That line is buried under the several dozen language options, but it is indeed under the "Desktop Entry" section. Now when I tap the Firefox icon in my task bar, and no firefox instance is open yet, it will prompt me with the profile manager selection.

If you want to have multiple profiles open at once, go to the internal page about:profiles. That's literally the text you put into the address bar. This is the only way I know to set up launching multiple profiles manually. But I think you could use the -P  flags instead of --profilemanager, passing in the correct profileName, to maybe launch multiple profiles at once on every start? Use case I can't think of for at the time, but, someone probably would.